# External Digital Signature with IText

Tags: itext, digital-signature, digital

I have a problem with external digital signature.
Im using IText 5.5.13 with java.

step 1 - preparing the pdf
step 2 - calculating the hash
step 3 - signing the hash
step 4 - combine hash to the source pdf

Im getting error: NO FIELD

Help is much apricated

Here is My Code:

```
//step 1 - preparing pdf to sign

 int contentEstimated2 = 8192;
 String src = "src.pdf";
 String dest = "dest.pdf";
 InputStream is = new FileInputStream(src);
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is);
 reader.setAppendable(true);
 ByteArrayOutputStream  baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
 FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
 PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, baos, '\0');
 PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
 String MotSigner = "GIF.jpg"; //IMAGE
 Image image = Image.getInstance(MotSigner);
 appearance.setImage(image);
appearance.setLayer2Text("");
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(250, 795, 300, 840);
appearance.setVisibleSignature(rect, 1, "sig1");
ExternalSignatureContainer external = new
ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
 MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance, external, size);

// step 2 - calculating the hash
  is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
  BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
  byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(is, digest.getMessageDigest("SHA-256"));

//step 3 - signing the hash 
    //sending hash to signer server. getting SignedBytes as result
 byte[] SignHashedPDF = Base64.decode(SignedBytes);


//step 4 - combine hash to the source pdf                                   
reader = new PdfReader(src);
FileOutputStream os1 = new FileOutputStream(dest);
ExternalSignatureContainer external1 = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(SignHashedPDF);
MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader, "sig1", os1, external1);
 os.close();

}                      

 



class MyExternalSignatureContainer implements ExternalSignatureContainer {

    protected byte[] sig;

    public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] sig) 
        this.sig = sig;

    }

    public byte[] sign(InputStream is) {
      return sig;

    }

    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
    }

}
```

Getting error on MakeSignature.signDeferred() as follows:

Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: No field
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.signDeferred(MakeSignature.java:291)
at test.SignerFinal.main(SignerFinal.java:219)

search answers on this forum

Comment: *"Im getting error: NO FIELD"* - what kind of error? On which line of your code? Which stacktrace?

Comment: Ty mkl.                                                                               
Getting error on MakeSignature.signDeferred() as follows:

Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: No field
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.signDeferred(MakeSignature.java:291)
at test.SignerFinal.main(SignerFinal.java:219)

Answer (score 0):

The issue already is visible in your abstract steps:

> step 1 - preparing the pdf
>  step 2 - calculating the hash
>  step 3 - signing the hash
>  step 4 - combine hash to the source pdf

In the last step you say that you plan to combine the (signed) hash with the *source* PDF. This of course is wrong, you have to combine it with the *prepared* PDF from step 1!

In your code, therefore, you have to replace

```java
//step 4 - combine hash to the source pdf                                   
reader = new PdfReader(src);
FileOutputStream os1 = new FileOutputStream(dest);
ExternalSignatureContainer external1 = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(SignHashedPDF);
MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader, "sig1", os1, external1);
os.close();
```

with something like

```java
//step 4 - combine hash to the prepared pdf
os.close();
reader = new PdfReader(dest);
String signed = "signed_dest.pdf";
FileOutputStream os1 = new FileOutputStream(signed);
ExternalSignatureContainer external1 = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(SignHashedPDF);
MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader, "sig1", os1, external1);
```

---

Furthermore, your variable names and your comments make me assume that your `SignHashedPDF` is a mere naked signed hash, not a complete CMS signature container. But `MakeSignature.signDeferred` for a `ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED` signature field value expects a CMS signature container!

If my assumption is correct, you will need to change your step 3 accordingly...

Comment: Hi, according to mkl i fixed my code and now i'm getting signature is invalid. I understand i need to use the getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes method. how do i impleament without chain. i'm not using Certificate. ty again.

Comment: *"I understand i need to use the getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes method."* - Yes, if you want to use the iText `PdfPKCS7` class. But there also are other CMS builder classes, e.g. in BouncyCastle, and there the methods to use to retrieve the bytes actually to sign may be called differently. *"how do i impleament without chain. i'm not using Certificate. ty again."* - interoperable digital PDF signatures are based on X509 certificates as carriers of the public key and identity of the signer. Thus, you should reconsider your system architecture...